# What do you call the additional money you pay when you buy a store or restaurant in return for many cutomers and nice facilities?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In Korea, it is customary for prospective buyers to pay the extra money to the owner of any business establishment when they want to buy it. The more customers and nicer facilities any store or shop has, the more money the buyer has to pay in order to buy it as a premium money.

For example, there is a store which costs 100,000 dollars to build. For the first year, its business is slow. Several years later, the store gets to have so many customers and its business is really good. The owner wants to sell his store at a great profit when someone wants to buy it.

What do you call "the additional money" which the buyer has to pay in addition to the original cost "100,000" dollars?

Comment: Such a custom doesn't exist in western culture, to my knowledge. The first payment on a piece of property is called the *deposit*, but it's not additional money but a part of the total cost of the property.....related: good-faith deposit http://financial-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Good+faith+deposit

Comment: @V0ight: I think the term "customary" in the question is misleading. It's not exactly a "custom" to pay more for a going concern with a high turnover and good facilities, than for a going concern with low turnover and poor facilities. But it certainly is an observable practice! It's just one example of something being worth more than it cost to build.

Comment: How about brand loyalty? They're purchasing the company, and its following. If a company were looking to acquire Coca-Cola, Coca-Cola might charge more than they're worth, because of the loyalty of their customers to choose them over someone like Pepsi. So by purchasing the restaurant in question, the owners might charge more because of the loyalty its customers have over another restaurant down the street.

Comment: Agree with Jessop. I doubt this is "customary", even in Korea. It's simple economics. The value of a business is absolutely affected by its customer base. This is an empirical result, not a "customary" one.

Comment: It needs to be noted that "nice facilities" is a physical characteristic, directly related to the value of the property.  If you have two otherwise identical buildings in the same neighborhood, one that's well-maintained and the other run-down, the first will have a higher property value.  This is totally unrelated to customer flow and other dynamics of the business.

Comment: Maybe OP is talking about NORTH Korea, where the additional money may be called a government tax.

Comment: From the point of view of the seller, the extra money is the "gain" or "profit" on the sale. But I don't think there is a word generally used by English speakers to describe this quantity from the buyer's point of view. Buyers (at least in the U.S.) generally don't care what the seller spent to build the building. The building _is_ an asset, but it might be valued at its replacement cost minus depreciation; in any case, its value might be greater or less than 100,000.

Answer (score 24):

**[Goodwill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodwill_(accounting))** may be a term that you are looking for:

> "The goodwill amounts to the excess of the "purchase consideration" (the money paid to purchase the asset or business) over the total value of the assets and liabilities."

More generally, you seem to be talking about the [intangible assets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intangible_asset) of the business, if you're defining "extra" as anything beyond the funds paid for the physical facility (as suggested by focus on the cost of building the store).

You could also be talking about the [capital gain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_gain) or [appreciation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_appreciation) in value, which would even apply to the real estate itself being sold for more than the $100K it cost to build.  Appreciation is more a result of rising prices of comparable assets, while the term "capital gain" leaves open the possibility that it may be more resulting from active efforts of the owner.

Economically rational sellers will generally sell for as much as they think the market will bear (i.e. as much as they think they can get) regardless of the resources they originally put into it.

Comment: Can I call the money "goodwill money"  or "premium money"?

Comment: You need to be a bit careful with the term. It has a particular meaning to accountants and tax people. There are regulations controlling the treatment of goodwill. Some of the concepts you mentioned are not goodwill, and some may be. Tangible assets and intangible assets that can be identified (and priced) are not goodwill. So it is usually just defined as whatever premium was paid above the fair market value of everything you can itemize.

Comment: OP specifically mentions _"The owner wants to sell his store at a great profit"_. This excludes _Goodwill_, since the seller is demanding a higher price. The buyer does not pay the extra just because he wants to.

Comment: @pipe: *Goodwill*, to business people, has a specific meaning, and it is often put on the accounts at a particular value. It does not mean 'the kindness of the buyer's heart'.

Comment: Goodwill is very much a reputation/behaviour concept. It is intangible, but in modern terms can include pseudo-tangible assets such as a customer base including email and analytical data. Look and feel can now be intellectual property and rebranding can destroy goodwill. The residual value of historical marketing and advertising (a sunk cost for the previous owner) can drive turnover for some time.

Comment: @pipe: I am sure the buyer in Korea also does not pay the extra money just because he wants to.

Comment: My understanding is that the term "goodwill", in an accounting sense, is used to specify the difference between the value of the physical facilities and inventory and the potential sale price of the enterprise.  It is kind of a "tangible intangible" -- tangible in that a price can be put on it with relative ease, intangible in that it cannot be held or touched, and it's often difficult to identify the elements of it with any precision.

Comment: -1 goodwill is for intangibles like reputation, not cleat things like customer relationships and quality of facilities, those are specific assignable resources.

Comment: @PeterShor: The comment that you're replying to is *about* the buyer in Korea.

Comment: -1 From the link you quote in your own answer: “*Examples of identifiable assets that are **not** goodwill include a company’s brand name, **customer relationships**, artistic intangible assets, and any patents or proprietary technology.*”

Comment: Thanks @Jim, I'd missed the "not."  Good catch. Answer updated.

Comment: @mxyzplk goodwill is specifically the premium paid over the market value of net assets. Customer relationship is an intangible only if contractual, in most other cases it is not. Considering a small shop, one could think it is likely the business does not have a lot of contractual relationships it can present as intangibles.

Comment: Goodwill and the word the OP is describing are completely different and they don't have the same definition in the legal context. Goodwill is an accounting term and it could be legitimately recorded in the balance sheet for tax purpose, but the word the OP is looking for is (more often than not) illegally pocketed without any record being made.

Comment: @Rathony I don't think OP is just talking about an unrecorded portion of a sale price.  It's quite legitimate to sell a business (on record) for more than the precise non-inflation-adjusted cost of building the structure.

Comment: Well, the question is a little misleading and confusing. It will be easier for you to understand what it means when you read my answer below.

Answer (score 15):

There isn't really a specific word for this in English. In general, the **value** of a business is not just the value of the building, fixtures, and fittings; a successful business simply has a greater value than an unsuccessful one.

You might apply *tangible*<sup>1</sup> and *intangible*<sup>2</sup> as [this page does](http://www.bytestart.co.uk/value-a-business.html):

> Although there are relatively easy ways to value certain parts of the business – such as stock, fixed assets...there will very probably be a sizeable **intangible** element to the value of a business.

In business terms, this kind of valuation is called an *income valuation* (as opposed to *liquidation valuation*) because it presupposes that the business will continue operating.

<sup>1</sup> tangible *"able to be touched or felt"* - [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tangible)

<sup>2</sup> intangible *"not made of physical substance : not able to be touched : not tangible"* [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intangible)

Comment: Yeah, to be honest I think there's a mistake in thinking that there's anything "extra" or "additional" from the buyer's perspective at all. For the seller, *appreciation* might be appropriate, though.

Comment: The word as defined by FASB, is in fact, Goodwill, as is stated in another answer. "For example, a company like Coca-Cola (which has been around for decades, makes a wildly popular product based on a secret formula, and is generally positively perceived by the public), would have a lot of goodwill. "

Answer (score 11):

If you're buying a **company** then the value of that company is factored into the price, usually some **multiple** of the yearly revenue. The specific multiple is determined by industry and often by credit agencies. The total value of the company, the **valuation**, therefore includes the physical and financial assets, as well as a measure of how much money it is expected to make.

If you're merely buying a **property** then the value of the company that inhabited that property is not considered meaningful, except insofar as it increased the inherit value of the property (through, say, fame), which in turn is a factor of what people are willing to pay for it. Such factors are usually called a **markup**. If the markup is high relative to similar properties, you are said to buying at a **premium**.

Notably any money you make on a property past what it cost you is simply called **profit**. All value is embedded in the property itself and is not differentiated between base cost and "tip".

Answer (score 5):

In that case you're buying at a [**premium**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/premium):

> a sum over and above a regular price paid chiefly as an inducement or
>   incentive

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: Hello, Frencesco. Welcome to ELU. Your answer was flagged as low-quality for its length and content. We encourage a definitive answer with a dictionary link, proper reference and examples. Please try to include them next time you answer a question here.

Comment: I am on a mobile. Will try to improve if the answer is not deleted earlier. It would be a shame since premium is used exactly in the meaning requested from the op. But so it goes :-)

Comment: Thanks for your comment in any case I appreciate that you took the time for it

Comment: The reason I edited your post and upvoted it is to prevent your answer from getting deleted. It is cleared from the review. Please expand your answer when you have time as I think it **is** the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Not as an additional payment, but you may pay more for a business that is a 'going concern' rather than just premises that you intend to close down, refurbish and then reopen potentially as a different type of business.

Comment: +1 for going concern, as you're not just buying the building, but also the business which is the setup, the customers, the credit, the suppliers, and the reputation!

Comment: @RemarkLima But the phrase *going concern* has a specific meaning in accounting and business context. It just means "a company which is operating". In other words, it means "a company which hasn't declared bankruptcy"

Comment: @Rathony which I'd argue is exactly what the question is asking.

Answer (score 1):

As @Francesco mentioned in the answer, it is called a *premium*. Another word that is used in the legal context is *foregift* which means:

> an advance payment or **premium** paid by a tenant on taking or renewing a
>   lease.

[Dictionary.Com]

The linked ['A study on the Foregift of Business Building'](http://m.dbpia.co.kr/Journal/ArticleDetail/NODE01782062) published by Korean Comparison Civil Law Academy has the following summary:

> ... the reality is that there are many incidents where money is being
>   given and received as **nominal Foregift**... the amount of the
>   **Foregift** is as much as several hundreds of millions of won and from the evidence that there are numerous cases of disputes regarding
>   the **Foregift** during lease disputes, it can be concluded that there
>   must be laws regarding the **Foregift** unlike the western countries
>   where they have the freedom of contrast and the government leaves it
>   to the tenants and landlords...

Many other legal documents translate the Korean word '[權利金](http://terms.naver.com/entry.nhn?docId=585195&cid=42094&categoryId=42094)' to 'foregift'.